Detecting equality of subgroups modulo $p$
Let $A,B \subseteq F$ be two subgroups of a free abelian group satisfying $A \subseteq B$. Also assume that for every prime number $p$ we have $B + pF = A + pF$. In other words, the images of $A,B$ in $F/pF$ are the same. Does this imply $A = B$?
The assumption is equivalent to $B \subseteq A + pF$. It does not say that $A/pA \to B/pB$ is an isomorphism (in fact, surjectivity precisely is $B \subseteq A + pB$), a priori, so the usual "local-global"-technique doesn't seem to apply.
To give some context, basically I want to prove a certain statement about abelian groups, and I have already proven it for vector spaces. So it is natural to apply this to $F/pF$, which is a $\mathbb{F}_p$-vector space.

If I'm not mistaken, there are groups in which the hypothesis is trivially satisfied—infinitely divisible groups like $F=\Bbb Q$. So it might be important to restrict to free abelian groups.

That's right. I have added this.

I think the assumption $B \subseteq A + pB$ for all prime $p$ is equivalent to $B/A$ being divisible, not to $p \cdot (B/A) = 0$.

Sorry, you are right. I have edited accordingly.

Counterexample
Let $B = F = \mathbb{Z}^{\oplus \mathbb{N}} = \left< e_1, e_2, e_3, \ldots \right>$ and define $A$ as the subgroup generated by $\{ e_n - n! \cdot e_{n+1} : n \in \mathbb{N} \}$. The subgroup is proper because $e_1 \notin A$. It remains to prove that for every (prime) number $p \in \mathbb{N}$ and $b \in B$, the coset $b+A$ contains an element divisible by $p$.
Let $b = \sum_{i=1}^m \beta_i \cdot e_i$ for some $\beta_1, \ldots, \beta_m \in \mathbb{Z}$, where wlog $m \geqslant p$. Since $e_n \equiv n! \cdot e_{n+1} \pmod{A}$, we have $b \equiv k \cdot e_m \equiv k \cdot m! \cdot e_{m+1}$ for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$, and $k \cdot m! \cdot e_{m+1}$ is divisible by $p$.
